# Scrapy, using the shell to access a page after an existing spider log in ... (login and then go from there)

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy

I am reading  https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html#creating-a-project and see I can access a Scrpay Shell like `scrapy shell "http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/1/"`

Only all websites that I crawl I need to

- log into using uname/passwd (stored in a method)
- go to some overview page with pagination
- from there open individual product pages (where we scrape the actual data)

**Question**: how can I use the shell to start 1 existing spider by name. Then make it log in and stop, so I can use the shell to access the Response?

**Question**: how can I make it stop on the 1st category page? or how can I make it stop on the first product page?

thx! appreciate your feedback

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to start a scraper and get access to the scrapy shell on a certain page, is to put the following into the method where you want to see the response:

```
def parse(self, response)
    from scrapy.shell import inspect_response
    inspect_response(response, self)
```

When you launch the spider with `scrapy crawl ...`, it will open scrapy shell where you can check the response.